# Popen as minimized datached process

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I want to launch a process in Windows and have it live independent of the parent process and launch minimized.

I have found the creation flags launch the process the way I want but the STARTUPINFO does not appear to have any effect.

```py
SW_MINIMIZE = 6

si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE
process = subprocess.Popen(my_exe, 
                           cwd=path_to_exe,
                           shell=True,
                           startupinfo=si,
                           creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`START` (an internal command in `cmd.exe`)](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) as follows (parameter `/MIN` means *Start window minimized*):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    f'start "" /MIN "{my_exe}"', 
    cwd=path_to_exe,
    shell=True)
```

Tested in a real Windows 10 environment using

- `path_to_exe` - an unusual path with `cmd`-poisonous chacacters,
- `my_exe`- file name containing a space, and
- `my_exe` -  run with some parameters.

```
import subprocess
path_to_exe = r'd:\bat\Unusual Names\This&That!'
my_exe = "CLIParser Pause.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen(
    'start "" /MIN "my_exe" /param 2', 
    cwd=path_to_exe,
    shell=True)

print(process)
```

**Output** (program launched minimized and runs independently of the parent `Python` process):

```
python .\SO\73951832.py
```

> ```
> <Popen: returncode: None args: 'start "" /MIN "CLIParser Pause.exe" /param 2'>
> ```